# How to append a href link with a select tag value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to change a href link based on two different select tags changed

So far I have got it to append with 1 select tag, however i cannot get it to work with the other. 
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

```
$('#to').on('change', function() {
    var value2 = $(this).val();
});

var base_href="/converter/";

$('#from').on('change', function() {
    var value=$(this).val();

    if (base_href=="")
       base_href = $("#cch-link").attr("href");

    $("#cch-link").attr("href",base_href+value+'-to-'+value2);
});
```

Comment: You don't have the scope to access `value2`

Comment: so do I have to but the first on change function into the second onchange? is there a or is there a where I can specify on change on 2 elements.

Comment: Just bind a single change handler for both elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the `value2` variable in the context of the first handler, outside of that context the variable is `undefined`, you can define a *global* variable or:

```
var base_href = "/converter/";

function setHref() 
{
   $("#cch-link").attr('href', function() 
   {
       var to = $('#to').val();           
       var from = $('#from').val();

       return base_href + from + '-to-' + to;
   });
}

$('#to, #from').on('change', setHref); // .change();
```

Comment: Works perfectly your a genius, Thanks. Any advice on how to get good at JavaScript and jquery I'm a total noob.

Comment: @user3035731 You are welcome. Thanks for saying that, but I'm not... :). I would suggest reading Flangan's [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do), also don't forget the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: thanks hopefully one day I will get to your level of javascript.